# Sprichwort "beobachteter Topf kocht nicht"?

Tags: idiom

Im Englischen gibt es das Sprichwort "a watched pot never boils", was heißt, dass ein Ereignis nicht (so bald) eintritt, wenn man dringend darauf wartet. Ich dachte, es gäbe das gleiche Sprichwort im Deutschen ("ein beobachteter Topf kocht nicht"), aber ich finde im Web nichts.

Wie heißt die deutsche Version von "a watched pot never boils"?

Comment: Handelt es sich um eine Alltagsanwendung der Heisenbergschen Unschärferelation?

Comment: Eher Quanten-Zenon-Effekt.

Comment: *Gut Ding will Weile haben* wäre nah dran, ohne die Übertreibung *nie*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meiner Ansicht nach gibt es für dieses Sprichwort keine (verbreitete) Version im Deutschen.

Diese [Website](https://freie-referate.de/englisch/englische-sprichwoerter-redewendungen) hat eine leidlich große Übersicht über englische Sprichwörter. Im letzten Abschnitt sind mehrere Sprichwörter aufgeführt, zu denen der Autor keine deutsche Entsprechung kennt. Das angefragte ist auch darunter.

Diese [Website](https://www.phrasen.com/uebersetze,A-watched-kettle-pot-never-boils,57875,e.html) versucht sich daran, eine sprichwort-artige Entsprechung zu kreieren:

> Ungeduld führt nicht zum Ziel

allerdings zeigt hierzu eine Rückwärtssuche, dass dieses Sprichwort nicht verbreitet ist.

Comment: Wenn der Website-Autor es sich ausgedacht hat, um die Lücke zu schließen, ist es *per definitionem* kein Sprichwort. Ein Sprichwort ist ein Sprichwort, wenn es mehrere Menschen (oder eine ganze Sprachgemeinschaft) über einen längeren Zeitraum hinweg in bestimmten Situationen verwenden.

Answer (score 5):

In zwei 2-sprachigen Wörterbüchern finde ich:

> *Nur keine Ungeduld!*

Das ist zwar ein Appell und beschreibt nicht das Gefühl des Sich-Dahinziehens des Erwarteten, ist aber immerhin idiomatisch. Geläufig ist mir persönlich auch die Wendung:

> *Je mehr man wartet  // Je ungeduldiger man ist, desto länger dauert's.*

Ansonsten gibt es noch zwei Verse von Von Logau:

> *Leichter träget, was er träget / Wer Geduld zur Bürde leget.*

Aber das ist von 1654, kennt also (so gut wie) niemand mehr, und auch die Verse sind ein Appell an die Geduld.

Der Appell-Charakter scheint typisch zu sein, denn er findet sich wieder auch im gegenwartssprachlichen

> *Mit Geduld und Spucke fängt man manche Mucke.*

Answer (score 3):

Ein Sprichwort, das mit einem Kochtopf zu tun hat, kenne ich nicht, aber ich kenne zwei andere, die eine ähnliche, wenn auch nicht ganz gleiche Bedeutung haben, weil beide ebenfalls die Ungeduld, die man beim Warten hat, thematisieren. Zufällig haben beide mit Gras zu tun:

1. > Gras wächst nicht schneller wenn man daran zieht.
2. > Nur Geduld! Mit der Zeit wird aus Gras Milch.

Comment: Interessanterweise gibt es im Chinesischen eine ähnliche Wendung (ein [*chengyu*](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinesische_Sprichwörter#Chengyu)) wie dein erstes Beispiel: *bamiao-zhuzhang* 拔描助长, den Schösslingen wachsen helfen, indem man daran zieht. Verdeutlicht natürlich das Gegenteil, nämlich, dass unkontrollierter Aktionismus und Enthusiasmus sowie Ungeduld nicht zum Ziel führen.

Comment: @Philipp: Ja, ich glaube, der Ursprung dieses Sprichworts ist China.

Answer (score 3):

"Bewachter Topf kocht nicht gern!", sagte meine Großmutter immer

Answer (score 2):

Die deutsche Entsprechung, die ich vor dem englischen Ausdruck kannte, war

> Eine Tür im Blick geht niemals auf.

Als ich den englischen Ausdruck hörte, kam er mir seltsam vor, denn das Erlebnis mit der ewig zu bleibenden Tür hatte ich – wie wohl jeder – schon als kleines Kind, während man mit Töpfen in dem Alter eher selten zu tun hat.

Ich glaube nicht, dass der obige Ausrdruck das eigentliche deutsche Sprichwort ist, aber irgendwas mit Türen muss es wohl sein.

Comment: Das klingt passend, habe ich aber noch nie gehört. Könnte das ein regional verwendeter Ausdruck sein?

Comment: Google findet diesen Ausdruck nur... hier. <g>

Answer (score 1):

Nach längerem Grübeln und Erörtern kamen uns über einem Glas Wein folgende zwei Wendungen in den Sinn:

> Unverhofft kommt oft

Das ist zwar oberflächlich besehen genau das Gegenteil von "Der Topf in den man kuckt, kommt nie zum Kochen", aber: Man kann Dinge ja auch durch ihr Gegenteil ausdrücken. Immerhin ist es eine verbrieft und versiegelt stehende Redewendung im Deutschen.

> Je mehr man wartet, desto länger dauert's.

Das ist nun keine eigentliche Redewendung (dazu ist es sprachlich nicht elaboriert genug), aber es ist definitiv eine plausible, alltagssprachliche Fassung des Kochtopfgedankens.

> Gut Ding will Weile haben.

Eine klassische Redewendung im Deutschen. Sie passt natürlich auch zur hier erörterten Topfsituation. Sie ist aber eben sehr allgemein, und es mangelt ihr die Kraft der Bildhaftigkeit, die dem originalen Kochtopfspruch eigen ist.

Ach so, und dann natürlich jetzt noch was oben schon stand:

> Der Topf, in den man starrt, kocht nie.

Das habe ich zwar noch nie gehört (vielmehr mir gerade ausgedacht), aber es entspricht den stilistisch-formalen Kriterien von Sprichwörtern<sup>1</sup> und macht darum gut, was dem zweiten Vorschlag fehlte. Das wäre dann eine sprichwortsprachliche Übertragung des englischen Vorbilds.

---

<sup>1</sup> Gängige Lexik, Rhythmus, Metaphorik